# Convert MM-DD-YY HH:MM to a valid RSS Date using sed

Tags: shell, unix, date, sed

Is there anyway to convert a MM-DD-YY HH:MM date to a valid RSS Date **using sed**? For example I want to convert `02-26-12 14:33` to `Sun, 26 Feb 2012 14:33:00 +0100`...
(seconds should always be `00`)

Comment: Looks like a really hard task to get 39 seconds from nowhere.

Comment: Ups sorry, I forgot to mention that seconds doesn't matter

Comment: Is it important to use `sed` specifically?

Comment: Why do you have to use Sed if Awk does the trick?

Comment: But if you come up with a different solutions then it's okay too...

Comment: Why `02-26-12` is not `26 Feb 1912`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach using `sed` and with the help of the `Bourne shell`. I added the LANG environment variable because my original language is spanish.

```
sed '
  s/^\([0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)\(.*\)$/date -d \"\2-\1\3" +\"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z\"/
' <<<"02-26-12 14:33" | LANG=en sh
```

Output:

```
Sun, 26 Feb 2012 14:33:00 +0100
```